# How to sign AWS MediaPackage URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert, aws-mediaservices, aws-mediapackage

I'm trying to work out how to stop someone from simply copying the asset URL from the resulting AWS MediaPackage Asset and using it outside of my website.

As in, I'm trying to lock down a HLS **.m3u8** file so it can only be used by authenticated users. I'm not asking about DRM since it's not meant for authentication.

Typically with AWS S3, you can sign the URL so that the URL will expire after a certain time period which is perfect. MediaPackage doesn't seem to support this however or allow you to adjust the URL access to private users.

One solution would be to place CloudFront in front of the MediaPackage asset and sign that URL. The issue with that is the content within the **.m3u8** is still not protect and the streaming clips can still be reconstructed without the main URL. As in, the **.m3u8** file is made up of other **.m3u8** files. So once the main **.m3u8** file is downloaded, then the inner **.m3u8** files are unprotected.

I have seen this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/cdn-auth.html however I'm using Video On Demand, which it doesn't support.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wondering if you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: The closest I got was locking down the whole S3 bucket and using hls.js I was able to get the URL that was about to be loaded of which I could then sign.

The problem with this approach is that not all browsers, like Safari, support media extensions. So this approach wouldn't work. The best you could do is get the playlist file sent to a server, loop through each entry and sign them. It's pretty messy.

Comment: I appreciate the update!